# What is correct name for something in unit-test that must "provoke" functions to errors?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, error-handling

By 'something' I mean input data, that potentially can lead function to unexpected behavior, primarily, and other things like that, which purpose is to test 'negative' conditions for a function.
ps
By the way - what name also used for 'positive' things?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether there's a specific, "official" name for data like this, other than something rather generic like "test case." You could potentially get more specific with something like "positive test case" and "negative test case."

However, I once worked on a team that handled a lot of email messages, and boy is email data messy ! Our system would periodically receive an email message that would somehow bring the entire system down, so we started saving these messages in our test database with the label "messages of death." We would run all known messages of death through our code during testing to make sure the system would stay up in the face of these malformed inputs.

Comment: 'messages of death' = LOL